# Apple Remote + Spotify?

Tags: spotify, apple-remote-desktop

I have a 2010 MBP on Lion, and use Spotify pretty heavily - is there any way that I can have my remote control spotify, rather than it waking up iTunes every time (which would be fine but I don't have any playlists)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [SpotifyIrRemote](http://spotifyirremote.gonzie.com/) which works on Lion.

Comment: Awesome! Worked a *dream*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iOS [Spotify remote](http://itunes.apple.com/app/remoteless-for-spotify/id353392482) instead.

There are a few options listed on [Spotify's website](http://www.spotify.com/uk/about/spotify-on-the-web/apps-remote-controllers/)

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is to use spotify itself, from an idevice (ipad, iphone) with spotify installed. If using the same spotify account, one can control what plays (and what volume).

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for spotify called Spotify Mac Remote, you can get it from the developers website [here](http://themacbox.co.uk/smr/). It works great with my universal remote, should work just as great with the apple remote.

**developers description:**

> Spotify Mac Remote is a plugin for Spotify that allows you to use your Mac’s IR remote control & multi-touch gestures to Play, Pause and change tracks.
>   The next, play/pause and previous buttons work exactly as you’d expect, the volume buttons control the system volume and holding the menu button quits Spotify – in case you want to use Frontrow.

Comment: I installed this, but unfortunately while it stops the remote using iTunes, it doesn't  seem to hook fully to Spotify - I'm running Lion, is tehre something else I need to do?

Comment: I'm still running Snow Leopard so I can't really tell you anything in regards to Lion. Play/pause, prev/next & volume is working properly. I didn't do anything special.

Comment: I guess you could try mailing the guy who made the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I just made an app that lets you control Spotify with your Apple remote

http://jlynx.net/programs/?program=SleepTimer

(I will make the source available soon)

Comment: Can someone tell me why this was down voted?